# what is the space complexity of std::map in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

suppose I used a map data structure from std::map (c++) of N elements which is like the following:

```
map<int,bool>m;
```

what is the space complexity here(for N elements)?
is it just

```
O(N*(sizeof(int)+sizeof(bool)))
```

or something else adds up which I am missing?

Comment: I'd assume `N * sizeof( node_type )` (`node_type` is implementation specific)

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of space complexity and the big O notation, since you have constants in there. Map is just O(n)

Comment: I just solved a problem which was giving me memory limit error (I used map ds in that implementation), right after replacing the map with array of bools I managed to cover up memory limit

Comment: nope , I am not talking about time complexity.

Comment: @panic Big-O is not per se time complexity, even though that is the one most often meant when it isn't spelled out. If you don't want to disregard the constant factors, ask for space use, and remember the allocator overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the space complexity of std::map in c++?

The standard does not mandate spatial complexity of container implementations.

But in practice, the asymptotic space complexity (in number of bytes allocated) is O(N) for all standard containers in reasonable implementations.

Comment: Beware the DS9K, where insanity comes standard. ;-)